# How to add existing DBase to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

We use phpmyadmin (4.6.6deb5) to admin some MariaDB-databases (10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.10.2 - Ubuntu 18.10) which are added and design by phpadmin.

Now we add a database and a user by using the command line.

This new database and the user is not listed in phpmyadmin.

Is it possible to get the new database and its user to phpmyadmin?

TIA, martin

Comment: If your installation of phpMyAdmin has a left pane click on the refresh button and any additional databases that were added other ways should show up. It is the rightmost icon below the phpMyAdmin banner in the left pane.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your database ( database.sql). In phpmyadmin with import option or via command 
**mysql -u username -p new_database < data-dump.sql**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb